# Why is the onclick event running 2 different functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am trying to run a function by clicking Modify2 or Edit2 in the code.
It runs all the time the function defined with onClick and then showCard again

1. List section loads
2. Select an entry of the list, it will run showCard and loads the item.
3. Clicking on Edit2 or Modify2 triggers showConn and right away showCard again

It should just trigger showConn !

And why is it running showCard right after showConn?

Thanks for any suggestions.

The Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(true);
  const [card, setCard] = useState(false);
  const [netconn, setNetconn] = useState(false);
  const [networks, setNetworks] = useState([]);
  const [network, setNetwork] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":3001/networks/list")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setNetworks(responseJson.data);
      });
  }, []);

  let showCard = (id) => {
    console.log( "Show Card");
    fetch(window.location.protocol+`//`+window.location.hostname+`:3001/networks/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setNetwork(responseJson.data);
        setList(false);
        setNetconn(false);
        setCard(true);
      });
  };
  
  let showConn = (id) => {
    console.log( "Show Connection");
    setList(false);
    setCard(false);
    setNetconn(true);
  };
  let showList = () => {
    setCard(false);
    setNetconn(false);
    setList(true);
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  const handleGetconn = (event,id) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(id);
    showConn(id)
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {netconn ? (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-auto">
            <div
              onClick={() => showCard(network._id)} 
              className="btn btn-primary">Submit</div> 
            <div 
              onClick={() => showList()}
              className="btn btn-default">Cancel</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
      {list ? (
        <div className="list-group">
          {networks.map((network) => (
            <li
              key={network._id}
              onClick={() => showCard(network._id)}
              className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              {network.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : null}
      {card ? (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-auto">
            <div 
              onClick={(e) => handleGetconn(e,network._id)} 
              className="btn btn-success">
              Modify2
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => showConn(network._id)} className="btn btn-primary">
              Edit2
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => showList()} className="btn btn-default">
              Back
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**UPDATE** the code and added () => to onclick tags where it was missing

Comment: Can you reproduce this in codesandbox ?

Comment: @BARNOWL: Here is a link [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-sun-hfu824)

Comment: Someone below probably solved your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function `showCard` on every render here:

```
onClick={showCard(network._id)}
```

In the code excerpt above, the onClick prop value is the return value of the function call which is called on every render.

The `<li>` element has the `onClick` prop set correctly.

```
onClick={() => showCard(network._id)}
```

Here, the onClick prop value is a reference to a function which is called on click event.

Comment: the li onclick is working correct and is only triggering the showcard() once. The div onclick's in the card section are triggering once the showConn() AND the showCard() instead of only the showConn

Comment: Edited the answer for clarity. If you call a function instead of passing a reference to it, it will be called on every render and therefore after any state change.

Comment: Thanks @mkert for clarifying. It is working after I made the change.